# VBA"Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA coding so I might be missing some basic information. I tried to find the error, but it was too hard for me to find it. The error is at the `W = Selection.Offset(0, -2).Value` line. Here is the code

```vb
Sub Ret_Calc()
Dim D, W As Variant
Dim LnReturn() As Double
Dim errorcount As Integer, j As Integer
s = 301
ReDim LnReturn(1 To s)
ActiveCell.Select
For j = 1 To s
    D = Selection.Offset(1, -2).Value
    W = Selection.Offset(0, -2).Value
    If D = "N/A" Or W = "N/A" Then
        Selection.Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
        errorcount = errorcount + 1
        Exit For
        ActiveCell.Offset(j, 0).Select 'not i
        Else: Selection.Cells(1, 1).Value = WorkshetFunction.Ln(W / s)
        LnReturn(j) = Selection.Cells(1, 1).Value
        s = s - 1
    End If
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: If your `Selection` cell is A1 for example, attempting to offset by two columns to the left is undefined. That situation would result in your error. Also, here are some examples on [how to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/4717755)

Comment: Please describe in more detail what your code is supposed to do. Adding screenshots of the before and after usually helps a lot.

Comment: Won't have caused that error, but `WorkshetFunction` should be `WorksheetFunction`

Comment: Is `LnReturn` variable needed?  I can't see it doing anything except holding the value for the selected cell.

Comment: If you've got more than one cell selected when the code is started the line `ActiveCell.Select` will select the first cell in that selection. As only a single cell is selected after this `Selection.Cells(1, 1)` can be shortened to just `Selection`.